# Fastest Convert from Collection to List<T>

Tags: c#, collections

What I'd like to avoid:

```
ManagementClass m = new ManagementClass("Win32_LogicalDisk");

ManagementObjectCollection managementObjects = m.GetInstances();

List<ManagementObject> managementList = new List<ManagementObject>();

foreach(ManagementObject m in managementObjects){

    managementList.Add(m);

}
```

Isn't there a way to get that collection into a List that looks something like:

```
List<ManagementObject> managementList = new List<ManagementObjec>(collection_array);
```

Comment: Please tell us which framework that you are using.  2.0 has a different solution from 3.5

Answer (score 141, accepted):

What version of the framework? With 3.5 you could presumably use:

```
List<ManagementObject> managementList = managementObjects.Cast<ManagementObject>().ToList();
```

(edited to remove simpler version; I checked and `ManagementObjectCollection` only implements the non-generic `IEnumerable` form)

Comment: Your cast could fail, you need ManagementBaseObject instead.

Comment: Not if we want to create a List<ManagementObject>, we don't. Perhaps OfType<ManagementObject> would be a reasonable compromise?

Comment: how to cast managementobjectcollection to IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IPropertyData>> where propertydata is name and value alone?

Comment: I'd suggest you undo your edit as many people ending up here will be using other collections which may support generics.

Answer (score 43):

You could use

```
using System.Linq;
```

That will give you a ToList<> extension method for ICollection<>

Comment: I constantly hit this issue - "Why is there no `ToList()`"? .... Google .... DOH! I can never seem to remember to include `using System.Linq;`

Comment: There is not ToList() in ObjectCollection.

Comment: Include the dll or use the other answer to cast

Answer (score 5):

`managementObjects.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().ToList();` is a good choice.

You could improve performance by pre-initialising the list capacity:

```
    public static class Helpers
    {
        public static List<T> CollectionToList<T>(this System.Collections.ICollection other)
        {
            var output = new List<T>(other.Count);

            output.AddRange(other.Cast<T>());

            return output;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In reality, pre-initializing the capacity won't save you a huge amount of time. The list will grow with a doubling strategy, so it won't have to resize many times. Less code to maintain, too.

Comment: (especially when compared to the overheads of IEnumeable, and Cast's iterator block...)

Answer (score 4):

Since 3.5, anything inherited from System.Collection.IEnumerable has the convenient extension method OfType available.

If your collection is from ICollection or IEnumerable, you can just do this:

```
List<ManagementObject> managementList = ManagementObjectCollection.OfType<ManagementObject>().ToList();
```

Can't find any way simpler. : )

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
List<ManagementObject> managementList = new List<ManagementObject>(managementObjects.ToArray());
```

Not sure if .ToArray() is available for the collection.
If you do use the code you posted, make sure you initialize the List with the number of existing elements:

```
List<ManagementObject> managementList = new List<ManagementObject>(managementObjects.Count);  // or .Length
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as ManagementObjectCollection implements IEnumerable<ManagementObject> you can do:

```
List<ManagementObject> managementList = new List<ManagementObjec>(managementObjects);
```

If it doesn't, then you are stuck doing it the way that you are doing it.

Comment: The problem is: it doesn't; it only implements ICollection, IEnumerable, IDisposable

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Then he is stuck doing it the way that he is doing it.  The IEnumerable<T> ctor is doing the same thing basically anyways.

Answer (score -2):

you can convert like below code snippet

```
Collection<A> obj=new Collection<return ListRetunAPI()>
```