# Convert ICollectionView to List<T>

Tags: c#, list, datagrid, icollectionview

I am binding property type of ICollectionView on DataGrid controls in WPF, .NET 4.0.

I use `Filter` on `ICollectionView`.

```
    public ICollectionView CallsView
    {
        get
        {
            return _callsView;
        }
        set
        {
            _callsView = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CallsView);
        }
    }

    private void FilterCalls()
    {
        if (CallsView != null)
        {
            CallsView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(FilterOut);
            CallsView.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private bool FilterOut(object item)
    {
       //..
    }
```

**Init ICollection view:**

```
IList<Call> source;
CallsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(source);
```

**I am trying to solve this problem:**

For example source data count is 1000 items. I use filter, in DataGrid control I show only
200 items.

I would like convert `ICollection` current view to `IList<Call>`

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187913/c-fastest-convert-from-collection-to-listt

Answer (score 27):

You can try:

```
List<Call> CallsList = CallsView.Cast<Call>().ToList();
```

Comment: Works perfectly when working with `CollectionViewSource` for getting the list of currently visible items on the view.

Comment: As you can see here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015930/when-to-use-cast-and-oftype-in-linq) you can use `List<Call> CallsList = CallsView.OfType<Call>().ToList();` alternativly.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem in Silverlight, but its the same in WPF:

`IEnumerable<call> calls = collectionViewSource.View.Cast<call>();`

Answer (score 1):

Because [System.Component.ICollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't implement IList, you can't just call ToList(). Like Niloo already answered, you first need to cast the items in the collection view.

You could use the following extension method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Casts a System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView of as a System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;T&gt; of the specified type.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TResult">The type to cast the elements of <paramref name="source"/> to.</typeparam>
/// <param name="source">The System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView that needs to be casted to a System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;T&gt; of the specified type.</param>
/// <returns>A System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;T&gt; that contains each element of the <paramref name="source"/>
/// sequence cast to the specified type.</returns>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="source"/> is <c>null</c>.</exception>
/// <exception cref="InvalidCastException">An element in the sequence cannot be cast to the type <typeparamref name="TResult"/>.</exception>
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1002:DoNotExposeGenericLists", Justification = "Method is provided for convenience.")]
public static List<TResult> AsList<TResult>(this ICollectionView source)
{
    return source.Cast<TResult>().ToList();
}
```

Usage:

```
var collectionViewList = MyCollectionViewSource.View.AsList<Call>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use an extension method to convert:

```
IList<Call> source = collection.ToList();
```